# how to import dvd rental database on mac. The postgres tutorial only gives instructions for windows

Tags: postgresql

I have downloaded the dvd rental.tar file on my desktop. followed the below instructions

```
pwd
/Users/O2/tools/postgres
mkdir dvdrentaldb
initdb dvdrentaldb
```

I get the following message

> initdb directory "dvdrentaldb' exists but is not empty If you want to create a new database system either remove or empty the directory or run initdb with an argument other than "dvdrentaldb"

I have downloaded the dvd rental.tar file on my desktop. followed the below instructions

```
pwd
/Users/O2/tools/postgres
mkdir dvdrentaldb
initdb dvdrentaldb
```

post this i am using the following code

```
pg_restore -U O2 -d dvdrentaldb dvdrental.tar
```

i get syntax error at or near "pg_restore"

I get the following message

> initdb directory "dvdrentaldb' exists but is not empty If you want to create a new database system either remove or empty the directory or run initdb with an argument other than "dvdrentaldb"

Comment: Well, then delete the directory before running `initdb`. Probably leftovers from a previous attempt.

Comment: still not working.. any more ideas

Comment: The tutorial to  [load the database](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/) does not mention `initdb` anywhere. That program is part of the installation process for Postgres. It's not something you do, once Postgres is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this from reddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/93uuhg/can_anyone_get_this_sample_database_tutorial_to/

```
createuser -s dvdrental
createdb dvdrental -O dvdrental
pg_restore -U dvdrental -d dvdrental ./dvdrental.tar
```

Comment: Which is essentially the same what the tutorial page explained: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/